# Override FLTheme Class Function in WordPress child theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to override a class's function output, but it seems that it cannot be overwritten. The function in the FLTheme Class has a css class i need to change is (**class="container"**):

```
    static public function woocommerce_wrapper_start()
{
    $layout = self::get_setting('fl-woo-layout');
    $col_size = $layout == 'no-sidebar' ? '12' : '8';

    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    self::sidebar('left', 'woo');
    echo '<div class="fl-content ';
    self::content_class('woo');
    echo '">';
}
```

All i am trying to do is to change the class **from "container" to "container-fluid"**. Tried to copy the file in my child theme's classes directory but it does not override the original one. Also, i don't want to change the original file because the changes will be lost after any theme update. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to extends the FLTheme Class ? So you can overwrite or extend his function.

```
class MyCustomClass extends FLThemeClass {
   static public function woocommerce_wrapper_start()
   {
     $layout = self::get_setting('fl-woo-layout');
     $col_size = $layout == 'no-sidebar' ? '12' : '8';

     echo '<div class="container">';
     echo '<div class="row">';
     self::sidebar('left', 'woo');
     echo '<div class="fl-content ';
     self::content_class('woo');
     echo '">';
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and got: Fatal error: Class MyCustomClass may not inherit from final class (FLTheme) in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\roche\wp-content\themes\child\functions.php on line 189